# mysql bulk process data

Tags: php, mysql, bulk

I have a MYSQL DB with three tables

Table 1 - Business
Has 200,000 plus records.
Two of the 20 fields in this table are category and subcategory
Both fields store numbers that reference the tables 2 and 3 respectively.

Table 2 and 3 - Category and Subcategory

Each of these tables stores two fields a number Id and the text name for the category.

For example Category or Subcategory table - ID:32 /Name:Pet Supplies

I need to process table 1 so that i check each records category and subcategory, grab the text name reference from both category and subcategory tables and put the output into a new field in table 1.

I hope someone can help guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Not clear what the use of storing the string in table 1 is.

Comment: Basically, its how I identify what category/subcategory, the business is in.

Comment: You probably have misunderstood the SQL [`JOIN` concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE business, category
SET business.categoryName = category.name
WHERE business.categoryID = categoy.ID;
```

Repeat for subcategory.

Better, delete the strings from the `business` table and get the category like this when you need it

```
SELECT b.name, b.whatever, c.name, s.name 
FROM business AS b, category AS c, subcategory AS s
WHERE b.categoryID = c.ID AND b.subcategoryID = s.ID;
```